# I want to call a mysql query after 5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I want to call a mysql query after 5 seconds.My code is below but it is not working please help me:

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("test",$connect);

$time= date('s');

$time2 = $time+5;


if($time==$time2){
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET name='John'
where user_name='test'");

}

?>
```

Comment: Once you set `$time= date('s');` then the value of `$time` is set unless you explicitly change it again... that's the thing with variables, they don't arbitrarily change themselves

Comment: You mean you want to freeze whole page for 5 seconds and execute query? oO

Comment: @bartek - in a day and age where users are clamouring for faster web pages, it makes a refreshing change to find a developer who deliberately wants to keep their users waiting.... the buzz of anticipation and expectancy

Comment: @MarkBaker Treat them mean, keep them keen.

Comment: @Muhammad Aqib - you need to explain what is the goal of this freeze, as you can see it is strange what you are doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the sleep function:

```
sleep(5);
//run query
```

Your code:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("test",$connect);

sleep(5);

mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET name='John'
where user_name='test'");
```

By the way, I must note that this sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: but the sleep(5); function is not reloading page for 5 seconds.i want to call a query after 5 seconds of page load.

Comment: @MuhammadAqib Then you will need to call an Ajax request 5 seconds after the page has loaded. This Ajax request will request a script that carries out the update.

Comment: You will need to read up on some examples about sending Ajax requests w/ JQuery.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test",$connect);

sleep(5); // will halt process for 5secs
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET name='John' where user_name='test'");
?>
```

Comment: Downvoted because you've stolen [Wayne's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24119130/3059284)

Comment: how u can say that I stolen !!! I have the same answer, and till I typed, Wayne answered the question (I haven't checked the answer though), and the time difference was not much when I answered. :)

Comment: That said, your answer does not add anything to Wayne's answer, so consider simply deleting it.